# How to run Clozure CL (Lisp) from a shell script on OS X?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I tried the following:

```
$ cat args.sh
\#! /Applications/ccl/dx86cl64
(format t "~&~S~&" *args*)

$ ./args.sh
```

Couldn't load lisp heap image from `./args.sh`

I can run lisp fine directly:

```
$ /Applications/ccl/dx86cl64
Welcome to Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.5-r13651  (DarwinX8664)!

?
```

Is it possible to write a shell script to run lisp code with Clozure CL? I am sure I am doing something silly.

I installed it from:  http://openmcl.clozure.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just following up on Charlie Martin's answer and on your subsequent question. The `dx86cl64 --eval <code>` will fire up a REPL, so if you want to fire up a given script then quit, just add this to the end of your script: `(ccl::quit)`. In the example you provided, this would do the trick:

```
#! /bin/bash 
exec /Applications/ccl/dx86cl64 --eval '(progn (format t "hello script") (ccl::quit))'
```

A nicer script would be the following:

```
#! /bin/bash
exec /Applications/ccl/dx86cl64 -b -e '(progn (load "'$1'") (ccl::quit))'
```

Put that into a file, `load-ccl-script.sh` (or other name of your choice). Then the following interaction works:

```
$ echo '(format t "weeee!")' > a.lisp
$ sh load-ccl-script.sh a.lisp
weeee!
$ _
```

Comment: Thanks! (I guess the 'sh' is redundant in 'sh load-ccl-script.sh a.lisp'...)

Comment: True, but without it I'd had to include the `chmod +x load-ccl-script.sh` line - the 3 characters were a bit more concise, and since this wasn't the purpose of the snippet i went the lazy way :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in your shebang line:

```
\#! /Applications/ccl/dx86cl64
```

In a UNIX file, the first 16 bits is called the "magic number".  It happens that the magic number for an executable script is the same bit configuration as the characters "#!".  The first 16 bits of your file have the same configuration as "\#", and UNIX won't buy that.

It is possible to add magic numbers, but it isn't easy or portable, so what you need is a way to invoke the script.  I'd suggest

```
#! /bin/bash
exec /Applications/ccl/dx86cl64
```

with appropriate arguments etc for your script.  (The `exec` builtin causes the current process to be loaded with the named executable *without forking*, so you don't have a spare process lying about.)

***Update***

In your particular case, you'll want something like

```
@! /bin/bash
exec /Applications/ccl/dx86cl64 --eval '(format t "~&~S~&" *args*)'
```

See the [command line args for Clozure](http://openmcl.clozure.com/manual/chapter2.5.html) for why.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this:

#! /bin/bash
exec /Applications/ccl/dx86cl64 --eval '(format t "hello script")'

That works, except that I get the lisp prompt after the method executes. How can I exit out of the loop?

$ ./args.sh 
hello script
Welcome to Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.5-r13651  (DarwinX8664)!
?

Comment: At least up until Clozure 1.4 `(bye)` isn't available. `(ccl::quit)`, however, is (thus `(quit)` will also work if you're on the `ccl` package).

Comment: I use about 6 variants of lisp and these sorts of things are maddeningly hard to keep straight.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure, that the kernel can load a Lisp memory image. The default behaviour is for the kernel to look for a file, which is named like the kernel binary with ".image" appended, i.e., if you start CCL using `dx86cl64`, then the image loaded is `dx86cl64.image` from the same directory. You can modify this behaviour by supplying the image explictely using the `--image` option. Try `dx86cl64 --help` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

See the scripts subdirectory of your ccl directory. It should have some scripts you can adapt and use.

Comment: I did. Unfortunately they are not lisp code scripts, but shell utilities.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the script like this from the command line:

```
/Applications/ccl/dx86cl64 myscript
```

can you?

I think that you need to call it like this (I don't have Clozure CL here, so I can't test):

```
/Applications/ccl/dx86cl64 -b -l myscript
```

So, your script should start like this:

```
#!/Applications/ccl/dx86cl64 -b -l
...
```